# About the select attribute in apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a question about how to use the select attribute in apply-templates. 
When I write this: `<ul><xsl:apply-templates select="authors/author" /></ul>`, what does it mean? Does it mean that it should apply a template where the author nodes are children of the authors node which is a child of the current node?

Following template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="author">  
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that it should apply a
>   template where the author nodes are
>   children of the authors node which is
>   a child of the current node?

Exactly.

Well, even more exatcly: It means the XSLT processor should apply templates **to all** `<author>` nodes who are children **of all** `<authors>` nodes who are children of the current node.

If there are mutliple templates that can match an `<author>`, the XSLT processor will decide *which* template to apply. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="author[not(@country = 'USA')]">
  <!-- will execute for any non-U.S. authors, specifically -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="author">
  <!-- will execute for all other authors -->
</xsl:template>
```